# Error when installing modeltime.gluonts::install_gluonts() in RStudio

Tags: python, r, ssl, rstudio, gluonts

I received an error when installing Python dependency for GluonTS Deep Learning in RStudio using modeltime.gluonts::install_gluonts(). I am new to using RStudio to run deep learning models. When loading the library, I received this message:

```
> library(modeltime.gluonts)
Loading required package: modeltime

── Python Dependency Check modeltime.gluonts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✖ GluonTS Python Dependencies Not Found
ℹ Available Options: 
1. [Option 1 - Use a Pre-Configured Environment]: Use `install_gluonts()` to install GluonTS Python
Dependencies into a conda environment named r-gluonts.
2. [Option 2 - Use a Custom Environment]: Before running `library(modeltime.gluonts)`, use
`Sys.setenv(GLUONTS_PYTHON = 'path/to/python')` to set the path of your python executable that is
located in an environment that has 'gluonts', 'mxnet', 'numpy', 'pandas', and 'pathlib' available as
dependencies.
Refer to 'Managing GluonTS Environments'
<https://business-science.github.io/modeltime.gluonts/articles/managing-envs.html> for more details.

── End Python Dependency Check ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

When I tried to install the dependency modeltime.gluonts::install_gluonts():

> modeltime.gluonts::install_gluonts()

```
ℹ Installing gluonts dependencies...


+ "C:/Users/wl/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" "create" "--yes" "--name" "r-gluonts" "python=3.7.1" "--quiet" "-c" "conda-forge"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1002)')))


Error: Error creating conda environment 'r-gluonts' [exit code 1]
```

How do I fix this error or troubleshoot it? If more info is needed do let me know.